# Do I Need to change Facebook Pixel after switching from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: advertising, facebook

Facebook has stopped showing our ads after a day from switching from http to https.

Comment: I think you've to edit your ads placement and add new URL(https). FB always check the status code of your landing page. And you move from http to https hence it's return 301 redirect status from http to https. That is why your ads is stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should switch the pixel to HTTPS.

Whenever you serve a website over HTTPS, all resources that your website loads (including the Facebook pixel) should always be loaded over HTTPS in order to prevent 'Mixed content' warnings from showing up in many web browsers.